# KeyListener is not triggered when releasing key after multiple keys have been pressed simultaniously

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I am programming a small application that uses key listeners. When a particular key is being pressed a timer is started and when that key is being released, the timer is stopped.

Now this works perfectly only when one key is being pressed at time. When I press 3 keys simultaneously all the three timers are started just fine. The problem I am experiencing is when the keys are being released one after the other. I tried using the InputMap and ActionMap but I experienced another problem.

```
  import java.awt.event.*; 
  import javax.swing.*;
  public class KeyTest extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
  private static final int UP_TIMER_DELAY = 200;
  // a timer for button "Z"
  private Timer upTimer;
  // a timer for button "X"
  private Timer upTimer2;

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
     new KeyTest(); 
  }

  public KeyTest() 
  { 
     this.addKeyListener(this);
     this.setSize(800,600); this.setVisible(true); 
  }


  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
  {
  //When Z is pressed
     if(e.getKeyCode()==90)
     {
        if (upTimer != null && upTimer.isRunning()) {
           return;
        }
        System.out.println("Button_Z is pressed");

        upTimer = new Timer(UP_TIMER_DELAY, 
              new ActionListener() {

                 @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                 }
              });       
        //Starting the timer for Button "Z" if pressed      
        upTimer.start();
     } 
     else {
        if (upTimer != null && upTimer.isRunning()) {
           upTimer.stop();
           upTimer = null;
        } 
     }
    //When X is pressed
     if(e.getKeyCode()==88)
     {
        if (upTimer2 != null && upTimer2.isRunning()) {
           return;
        }
        System.out.println("Button_X is pressed");

        upTimer2 = new Timer(UP_TIMER_DELAY, 
              new ActionListener() {

                 @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                 }
              });           
        upTimer2.start();
     } 
     else {
        if (upTimer2 != null && upTimer2.isRunning()) {
           upTimer2.stop();
           upTimer2 = null;
        }
     }
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
  {
  //When Z is released
     if(e.getKeyCode()==90)
     {

        if (upTimer != null && upTimer.isRunning()) {
           upTimer.stop();
           upTimer = null;
           System.out.println("Button_Z is released");
        }   
     }

     //When X is realeased
     else if(e.getKeyCode()==88)
     {

        if (upTimer2 != null && upTimer2.isRunning()) {
           upTimer2.stop();
           upTimer2 = null;
           System.out.println("Button_X is released");
        }  
     }
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
  { 
  // Do stuff. 
  } 
  }
```

Comment: *"I tried using the InputMap and ActionMap but i experienced another problem."* It would be more productive to solve that.

Comment: Aaaaaaaand what is the problem?

Comment: @looper When i press and hold "Z" it prints "Button_Z is pressed", while holding the "Z" key then press and hold "X", it prints another line "Button_X is pressed". Now The problem is when i release the "Z" key it does not print anything though its supposed to print "Button_Z is released". Try to compile and run it to see what i really mean.

Answer (score 3):

You cancel the timer when another key is pressed yourself.

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=90
Button_Z is pressed
Canceling Button_X timer
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=90
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=90
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=88
Canceling Button_Z timer
Button_X is pressed
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=88
Button_X is released
java.awt.event.KeyEvent[KEY_RELEASED,keyCode=90 // but timer already canceled
```

Comment: I really appreciate that, you helped me understand how the JVM executes this piece of code.